# Repository pattern and 1:1 relationships

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository

I currently create a Repository for each database table and a corresponding data class for the column values (object to pass around data).

I recently started using some 1 to 1 relationships and I'm not sure what would be the best way to implement them.

**For example**

If I have a User table and a UserSettings Table in a 1:1 relationship.

```
// Data classes (Holds all the field value for the table)
    public class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }       
    } 


     public class UserSettings
        {
            public int UserId { get; set; }
            public bool SomeSetting { get; set; }       
        }
```

**Questions:**

1. Should I always go through the User object to manipulate the UserSettings object, or should I be able to manipulate them
   independently?
2. Should I include the primary key field in the UserSettings object?
3. Should I store a reference to the USerSettings object in the User object?
4. Do I make two repo's one for User and one UserSettings, or do I handle everything in the Users Repo.

Comment: What is the purpose of having user settings separate from users?  What system  consumes only user settings outside of a login context?

Comment: I guess I could of used a better example

Comment: I doubt it - `User`/`UserSettings` is probably the single best question around 1:1 relationships.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time I've ever found a 1:1 relationship between aggregate roots to be useful is when the aggregate roots on either side of the relationship are managed by different domains.  They must **share the same primary key**, and therefore if they are both managed by the same domain then they are by definition **parts of the same aggregate root**.  I think you need to approach this question from a different angle:

1. Is the `User` object only going to exist for this application?
2. Do you expect that to always be the case?

If the `User` is a concept that resides entirely inside of this domain, then there's no reason to have a `UserSettings` aggretate root that has a 1:1 relationship with a `User`; you simply make `User.Settings` a way to retrieve the `UserSettings` for that `User`.  (And of course that obviates the need for a repository - it becomes the responsibility of the `UserRepository` to hydrate the `UserSettings` when it hydrates everything else on the `User`.)

But, if the `User` will eventually inform sessions for multiple domains, then `User` needs to represent **its own domain**, the services of which your application will consume.  Then, you gain a very real need to separate the `UserSettings` of this application from those of a different application.  The `User` is not specific to this application, but the `UserSettings` for that `User` is.

**NOTE** - In the interest of not refactoring your project *at this point*, if the answer to either question 1 or 2 above is "no", then you **should** make `UserSettings` a separate aggregate root within the same domain, in order to create a seamless transition when you eventually do move `User` into its own domain.

Comment: So if I "hydrate" the UserSettings object via User.Settings are the user settings going to remain mixed into the Users table? Is the Settings object just a container / value object to pass around data in code?

Comment: The repository is a persistence facade - whether you have one table or many is really not an application design consideration in and of itself.  As ian31 also mentioned, you seem to be approaching this problem from the wrong direction.  Make your decision about where `User` belongs, then design your domains around that decision.  Make your decisions about database design based on the requirements for the database.  The questions you ask when you're doing schema design are only "How should I store this?", never "What should I store?"

Answer (score 2):

1. What exactly do you mean by 'going through the user object' ?
2. IMHO, no.
3. You can, but I do not think you should.  Is there any reason why you'd want to know to which User the settings belong to ?  The only time you'd want to know that -imho- is when you persist it.  In your database, you need to know to which User, the UserSettings belong to.  In your model, I think you can suffice by a uni-directional relationship
4. You should only create a repository per aggregate root, in your case 'User' can be an aggregate root.  UserSettings is -imho- not even an entity but a value object.

Comment: For q1 I meant should I have to create a User object and tack on the UserSettings object to update the settings, or can it be independent (i.e. run a direct update query on the UserSettings table.) So the sub tables in 1 to 1 relationships are value objects and I should treat them as such?

Answer (score 2):

> I currently create a Repository for each database table

...

> // Data classes (Holds all the field value for the table)

It seems you're adopting a bottom-up (database first/database centric) approach which is uncommon in DDD. As the name Domain Driven Design implies, you usually rather start by modelling your domain, fleshing out your Aggregates, Aggregate Roots and Entities.

Aggregate roots usually have their own Repository while regular entities most often don't. To know whether an entity should be an Aggregate root, you have to ask yourself if that object is going to be one of the main entry points in the application, with a group of related objects gravitating around it and only obtainable through traversal of it.

User is an obvious candidate for an Aggregate root. User Settings in contrast isn't IMO a root, it belongs in the sphere of influence of a User. I'd make it a part of the User Aggregate and only obtainable through traversal of a User. It means having a reference to UserSettings in User but not necessarily the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I would ask yourself if a UserSettings can exist with out an associated user, and/or does a User always have an associated UserSettings. If so then the UserSettings could easily be made part of the User aggregate rather then being a separate aggregate itself. Yes in the database they will most likely be in different tables with 1:1 relationship between them, but this is a specific concern of the implementation of the repository. Your domain model could consider the UserSettings part of the user.